# WOL on macbook running ubuntu server

Tags: macbook, wake-on-lan, ubuntu-server

I am using an old macbook pro (2010) as server in my home lab.

It is running ubuntu server. I would like to use wake on lan on it, so I used:

**sudo ethtool -s INTERFACE wol g**

(with the name of my interface)

After I run:

**ethtool | grep Wake-on**

And I got:

**Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g**

Finally, from my pc I run:

**wakeonlan MAC-address**

(Replacing the MAC-addres)

And I have a message saying that the magic packet has been sent, but nothing happens.

I tested the same method on another laptop (not a macbook) and it works. I had to access the bios to enable WOL there (on the pc-laptop), but for the macbook I don't know how to do it.

Anyone know how to?

Thanks in advance.

PD. I managed the behavior of the lid such that it ignores when the lid is closed (instead of hibernate).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I’ve been search this particular issue on my 2018 MacBook Pro. I had a hunch what the issue was and was correct. The WOL is working but on macbooks it doesn’t wake up the screen! I have no idea why. I found ONE app on the AppStore that wakes mine:

OFF

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/off-shutdown-and-wake-on-lan/id529923825

It scanned my system and reported port 1984 as the upnp mapped wake on lan port. I forwarded 1984 external/1984 internal to my MacBook internal ip. And it wakes the display as well, why it goes and others don’t, hit me. It does run a helper app on the MacBook to enable other functions but I have a hunch it might be running a wol packet sniffer then launching a script to wake the display as well